# Imported service is undefined on abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ionic2

I have abstracted class `Collection`, which utilizes a service `Database` to initialize collections on a database. I have several subclass instances of `Collection`, which all need to do the same database initialization. So `Collection` is some kind of base class.

Suprisingly the imported service `Database` is `undefined` on the constructor of the subclass `FooCollection`. The constructor of the `Database` service is definitely called before the Foobar constructor.

Why is the imported service undefined on `FooCollection`? Is this a reason of misconception or related to the loading order of classes?

**`Collection.ts`:**

```
import { Database } from '../providers/database';
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export abstract class Collection {

  public name : string;

  constructor(public db : Database) {
     // db is undefined here -> crash
     db.doSomething();
  }
}
```

**`Database.ts`:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Database {

  private _db: any = null;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello Database Provider');
  }

  public doSomething(): void {
      console.log("doSomething");
  }
}
```

**`FooCollection.ts`:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Collection} from '../classes/collection';


@Injectable()
export class FooCollection extends Collection{
}
```

**`app.module.ts`:**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Start } from '../pages/page/start';
import { Database } from '../providers/database';
import { FooCollection } from "../providers/foocollection";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Start
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Start
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Database,
    FooCollection
   ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**`Start.ts`:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { FooCollection } from '../../providers/foocollection';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-start',
  templateUrl: 'start.html'
})
export class Start{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public f: FooCollection ) {
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed that explicitly importing `Database` again on `FooCollection` works fine:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Database } from './database';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Store } from '../classes/store';

@Injectable()
export class Calls extends Store {
  constructor(public db : Database) {
    super(db);
  }
}
```

This raises the question how imports are handled on subclasses of abstract classes.

Comment: Not sure if that helps but don't you need to call super() in your subclass's (FooColleciton) constructor?

Comment: Which Angular version do you use? Have you tried to make Collection non-abstract class and use it as a provider directly, e.g. {provide: FooCollection, useClass: Collection} ? Where and how is FooCollection used?

Comment: Does it work if you add the constructor in the subclass as well?
`@Injectable()
export class FooCollection extends Collection{
constructor(public db : Database) { super(db); }
}?

Comment: @Aer0 I  think that is automatically done if extending a class

Comment: @estus Ionic/Angular 2.2.1. I added code to the component that is using FooCollection. Making it a provider doesn't solve the problem, because I want to keep the base class which FooCollection is extending and Database is already a provider...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yep this one works, but would also means code redundancy. Imagine I have 10-20 classes where all of them have to import DataBase provider and pass it to super(db). Isn't there a easier solution?

Comment: It is not about solving a problem, it is about narrowing it down. I believe there were some changes in how DI works in inherited classes, but I don't remember if 2.2.1 was affected. Again, does it happen or not when Collection is a provider? If it's not, then try to upgrade Angular, otherwise stick to the workaround suggested by Günter Zöchbauer.

Comment: @kerosene exactly as estus said. Just to narrow down. It should work with recent Angular versions without duplicating the constructor (if the subclass doesn't have an explicit constructor at all)

Comment: It's not working if Collection is defined as provider (injectble). Upgrading angular might not be that easy, because Ionic is bound to certain angular versions. Gotta check out ionic beta versions with newer angular

Answer (score 2):

You should provide db in the module where it's used. Foo collection should be also provided because see the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/w6NuoVinl1v1n7aUSLog?p=preview).

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [Database, FooCollection]
```

Comment: There is only on module: **AppModule**, added app.module.ts definition as well

Comment: Can you instantiate a Database class?

Comment: More over the Collection is abstract and therefore instances of that class belong to a subclass which is an injectable instance, that should provide an injected instance of Database.

Comment: I can instantiate the Database class separately on a component (like Start.ts). That means every FooCollection that is extending my abstract class needs to import database and needs to pass it to the super constructor? That would be of course a solution but a lot of redundant code, because it needs to be done on several instances like FooCollectionA, FooCollectionB etc

Comment: @kerosene The instances should be taken from the container, see update.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot comment, so i write it here.
i've just upgraded my app from 2.4.5 to 4.0.0 , and now i face the same issue !
i've got an abstract service (a) that injects a cache service (as protected)
in extend that service (b) to add functionality.

and the extended service (b) is used in a resolver.

the resolver tries to call a method in service B, that uses one of the injected services in A.   but those injected services are undefined.
i've checked again , running in 2.4.5 - works like a charm